# Splits a string according to the specified length into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Splits a string according to the specified length into an array.

Does there exist an easy way to do this with an array in JavaScript?

I wrote the following function to do it, but is there something shorter or better?

```
function splitIntoArr(str, num) {
  let arr = [];
  let len = Math.ceil(str.length / num);

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     arr.push(+str.substring(i * num, i * num + num))
  }

  return arr;
}

splitIntoArr("123456789", 2)  # Outputs: [12, 34, 56, 78, 9]
splitIntoArr("123456789", 3)  # Outputs: [123, 456 ,789]
splitIntoArr("123456789", 4)  # Outputs: [1234, 5678 ,9]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression and `match` up to the desired number of characters:

```js
const splitIntoArr = (str, num) => str.match(new RegExp(`.{1,${num}}`, 'g'));

console.log(splitIntoArr("123456789", 2));
console.log(splitIntoArr("123456789", 3));
console.log(splitIntoArr("123456789", 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions and `match()`

```js
function splitIntoArr(str,num){
  let reg = new RegExp(`.{1,${num}}`,"g");
  return str.match(reg);
}

console.log(splitIntoArr("123456789", 2))  // Outputs: [12, 34, 56, 78, 9]
console.log(splitIntoArr("123456789", 3))  //Outputs: [123, 456 ,789]
console.log(splitIntoArr("123456789", 4))  //Outputs: [1234, 5678 ,9]
```

You could also do it using `reduce()`

```js
function splitIntoArr(str,num){
  return [...Array(Math.ceil(str.length/num))].reduce((ac,a,i) => [...ac,str.slice(i*num,(i+1)*num)],[])
}

console.log(splitIntoArr("123456789", 2))  // Outputs: [12, 34, 56, 78, 9]
console.log(splitIntoArr("123456789", 3))  //Outputs: [123, 456 ,789]
console.log(splitIntoArr("123456789", 4))  //Outputs: [1234, 5678 ,9]
```